# Storing User Settings in C# Application

Tags: c#, settings

After spending countless hours changing my code and removing everything that wont serialize and changing them to strings and writing functions to convert from Font/Color to strings and back again i've got fed up and decided to make my own basic serializer..

```
private void saveSettings()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(settingsObj).GetProperties();
    foreach (settingsObj s in settings)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(s.[property.Name]);
        }
    }
}
```

How do i refer to a variable using a string, in PHP i'd do:

```
$varIWantToRead = "foobar";
$varName = "varIWantToRead";
print $$varName;
```

Comment: posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done in the exe.config file. Here is a write up from Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx

You could also create your own class or struct and serialize them into XML:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Edit to answer your new question: 
Im not quite sure I know what your talking about but here we go:

```
In PHP: 
$varIWantToRead = "foobar";
$varName = "varIWantToRead";
print $$varName;


in c#: 
string varIWantToRead = "foobar"; 
string varName = varIWantToRead; 
Console.WriteLine(varName); // Outputs foobar
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i meant, in PHP its called a variable variable, i meant it as an example of what i'm after: `MessageBox.Show(s.[property.Name]);` that doesnt actually work..

Comment: what type is s.[Property.Name]  You may need to call .ToString()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default behaviour of winforms setting, Application Settings. [Take a look at what microsoft says in brief](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755.aspx) and also [goes into more details in another link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx)

XML is a dynamic way of keeping data, there are lots of samples online like [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) and [this microsoft link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813)

Comment: I need to programatically add profiles and from what I can see you have to define all the settings at design time..

Comment: well in the case of dynamic profiles you can use serialization/deserialization an XML to save user information in a flexible format.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, what object type can I use to store a class, so I can do something like: `profiles['profile1'].FontColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what i was looking for.

Thanks Guys.

[Serializing Lists of Classes to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178899/serializing-lists-of-classes-to-xml)

Comment: Would you mind selecting the user who answered your question.

Comment: I haven't gotten my solution to work correctly as yet, i'll post my solution when i have finished and select then.

Comment: What problems are you having?