# Recursive Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, xml-serialization

I need to serialize `myFamily` to an .xml file, I really don't know how to do it.

**Enums.cs**

```
public enum Genre {
    Male,
    Female
}
```

**PERSON.cs**

```
public class PERSON {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public List<PERSON> Parents { get; set; }
    public List<PERSON> Children { get; set; }

    public PERSON(string name, Genre genre) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Genre = genre;
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        List<PERSON> myFamily = new List<PERSON>();

        PERSON Andrew = new PERSON("Andrew", Genre.Male);
        PERSON Angela = new PERSON("Angela", Genre.Female);
        PERSON Tina = new PERSON("Tina", Genre.Female);
        PERSON Jason = new PERSON("Jason", Genre.Male);
        PERSON Amanda = new PERSON("Amanda", Genre.Female);
        PERSON Steven = new PERSON("Steven", Genre.Male);

        Andrew.Parents.Add(Tina);
        Andrew.Parents.Add(Jason);

        Angela.Parents.Add(Tina);
        Angela.Parents.Add(Jason);

        Tina.Parents.Add(Amanda);
        Tina.Parents.Add(Steven);

        Jason.Children.Add(Andrew);
        Jason.Children.Add(Angela);

        Tina.Children.Add(Andrew);
        Tina.Children.Add(Angela);

        Amanda.Children.Add(Tina);

        Steven.Children.Add(Tina);

        myFamily.Add(Andrew);
        myFamily.Add(Angela);
        myFamily.Add(Tina);
        myFamily.Add(Jason);
        myFamily.Add(Amanda);
        myFamily.Add(Steven);

        // serialize to an .xml file
    }
```

Comment: read this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178899/serializing-lists-of-classes-to-xml

Comment: a forgotten +1 to your question ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Serialize objects with circular reference you need to use [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx). To do so

- Add `[DataContract(IsReference=true)]` to `Person` class
- Add `[DataMember]` to your properties
- Instantiate your lists in constructor
- Remember to `using System.Runtime.Serialization;`

So your class should be:

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class PERSON
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<PERSON> Parents { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<PERSON> Children { get; set; }

    public PERSON(string name, Genre genre)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Genre = genre;
        Parents = new List<PERSON>();
        Children = new List<PERSON>();
    }
}
```

To Serialize:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(myFamily.GetType()); 
using (FileStream stream = File.Create(@"D:\Test.Xml")) 
{ 
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, myFamily); 
}
```

To Deserialize:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\Test.Xml"))
{ 
    List<PERSON> data = (List<PERSON>)serializer.ReadObject(stream); 
}
```

Comment: The test.xml only contains: `<ArrayOfPERSON xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WindowsFormsApplication1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>`

Comment: Neither, same result.

Comment: I see that DataContractSerializer is to produce XML, is there a similar solution for JSON serialization ?

Comment: @Inspi This may help: [How to preserve references and handle or ignore circular references in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: @Inspi Or this one with NewtonSoft: [Preserving Object References](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/preserveobjectreferences.htm)