# Windows Universal XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, windows, serialization, win-universal-app

I have been working on a kitchen app and it needs to save recipes. Everything works fine with the XML Serialization except `List<IngredientMeasure> IngredientList`. I have heard a lot of other people have had problems serializing lists of classes too, and I saw this: [Serializing Lists of Classes to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178899/serializing-lists-of-classes-to-xml).
I tried the solutions there, but none of them worked.
Here are the fields for the `Recipe` class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Recipe
{
    [DataMember]
    public static List<Recipe> RecipeList = new List<Recipe>();

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FilePath { get;  set; }

   [DataMember]
    public List<IngredientMeasure> IngredientList { get;  set; }

    [XmlArray("IngredientsList")]
    public List<string> Ingredients = new List<string>();

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> DirectionList { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> Notes { get; private set; }

    public Recipe()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the `IngredientMeasure` class:

```
public class IngredientMeasure
{
    [DataMember]
    public Ingredient ingredient;
    [DataMember]
    public Measure measure;

    public IngredientMeasure()
    {

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please could  you paste the exception?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, could you please paste the xml text you want to produce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you just mentioned, **`XmlArray` should be on the list of contained items** not on the list of string.

```
[DataContract]
public class Recipe
{

    [XmlArray("IngredientsList", XmlArrayItem(typeof(IngredientMeasure), ElementName = "IngredientMeasure"))]
    public List<IngredientMeasure> IngredientList { get;  set; }

    // ... other properties 
}
```