# C# - Serializing List of Object to XML using generic method

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm writing a housekeeping application for a program I administer and I'm hitting a bit of a brick wall when trying to serialize a `List` of custom classes to XML files.

[I found this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178899/serializing-lists-of-classes-to-xml) that covered using an `XMLSerializer` class to output Object data to XML. The key difference with what I'm trying to do is that I have a few different Lists containing unique data so I built a helper class with a generic static method to serialize/deserialize the data. The problem is that not all data is being serialized out so I can't deserialize it back into my application at a later date without encountering issues.

My method looks like this:

```
private static void SerializeObjectToXml<T>(List<T> inputList, string filePath)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, inputList);
            }
        }
```

My data Object looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot("NameAddress")]
    public class AppNameAddress
    {
        private string _OfficerCode;
        private string _TelephoneNumber;
        private string _EmailAddress;

        public string OfficerCode { get { return _OfficerCode; } }
        public string TelephoneNumber { get { return _TelephoneNumber; } }
        public string EmailAddress { get { return _EmailAddress; } }
        public string TeamName = "";
        public bool IsOfficerManager = false;

        public AppNameAddress() { }

        public AppNameAddress(Dictionary<string, object> data)
        {
            _OfficerCode = data["OfficerCode"].ToString().Trim();
            _TelephoneNumber = data["TelephoneNo1"].ToString().Trim();
            _EmailAddress = data["EmailAddress"].ToString().Trim();
        }
    }
```

And my List declaration looks like this:

```
[XmlArray("NamesAddresses"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(AppNameAddress), ElementName = "NameAddress")]
        public static List<AppNameAddress> NamesAddresses;
```

The problem is that the data being exported to the XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfAppNameAddress xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AppNameAddress>
    <TeamName />
    <IsOfficerManager>false</IsOfficerManager>
  </AppNameAddress>
  <AppNameAddress>
    <TeamName />
    <IsOfficerManager>false</IsOfficerManager>
  </AppNameAddress>
...
```

As you can see, the `OfficerCode`, `TelephoneNumber` and `EmailAddress` parameters are not being exported. The only difference I can see is that there is no `{ set; }` for those variables as I want them to be read-only after initialising the Object but I can't see why that would affect the `XmlSerializer`'s ability to read the data and output it to XML. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to add a public setter to those properties in order for them to be serialized. This post may be of interest - [serializing-private-member-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802711/serializing-private-member-data).

Comment: Thanks @CalC, that question provides a little more insight... might be worth marking this as a duplicate as that question basically answers what I had already?