# C# XML LINQ GroupBy from CSV File

Tags: c#

I am in the process of generating XML from a CSV file.

In the picture I attach the result I am waiting for

[image]

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(csvPath + csvName))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {

        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MapClass>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Data>().ToList();

         from w in records
         select

         // group by invoice number ?

        new XElement("INVOICE",
            new XAttribute("DATE",w._invoiceDate ),
            new XAttribute("NUMBER", w._invoiceNumber),
            new XAttribute("QTY", w._orderQty)  

        }
}
```

I want to display the data grouped by the invoice number with the amounts added up (equivalent to a pivot table). Can I ask you for a tip for me?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(csvPath + csvName))
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
                {

                    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MapClass>();
                    List<Data> records = csv.GetRecords<Data>().ToList();


                    var result = records.
                        GroupBy(x => x._invoiceNumber).
                        Select(x => new
                        {
                            // IGrouping does't contain 'Value" definition
                            InvoiceNumber = x.Key,
                            InvoiceQty = x.Value.Sum(y => y._orderQty),
                            InvoiceTotal = x.Value.Sum(y => y._invoiceTotal)
                        }).ToList();
                }

            }
```

Comment: `group record by record.InvoiceNumber into w`? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want to group a data by record.w._invoiceNumber and Sum  w._orderQty for each Invoice

Comment: See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/group-clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: GroupBy, Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count)

Comment: Btw you may want to declare your variable outside of the using block and only keep the `GetRecords` in it. Right now the Using is unnecesseray waiting to dispose the resource. ` List<Data> records;` is no cost.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178899/serializing-lists-of-classes-to-xml

Answer (score 0):

below code should give to data of table you expect, further you can generate XML you need

```cs
var result = records.GroupBy(x => x._invoiceNumber).Select(x => new { InvoiceNumber = x.Key, InvoiceQty = x.Sum(y => y._orderQty), InvoiceTotal = x.Sum(y => y._invoiceTotal) }).ToList()
```

Comment: I got information that in not allowed convert lambda to deletage

Comment: clarify, are you getting any error or exception with proper message.

Comment: GroupBy return Key Value structure. so Value is collection of Invoice for specific group

Comment: Ok , but I have a compile error with 'Value'. Do you have any idea ? I added this code above

Answer (score 0):

We can close this topic. I found a solution

```
var res =   from e in records
                        group e by e._invoiceNumber into g
                        where g.Count() >= 1
                        select new
                        {
                            Invoice = g.Key,
                            Total = g.Count(),
                            TotalQty = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32( x._orderQty.ToString()))
                        };


                        foreach(var item in res)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($" {item.Invoice}  :   {item.TotalQty}  ");
                        }
```